# Is it really safe that running `UPDATE t SET v=v-1 WHERE id= ? and v>0` without pessimistic row locking? (MySQL/Postgres/Oracle)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, oracle, mvcc

#### Overview

Assume that there is a table which controls stock amount information.

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    remaining_amount INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO products(id, remaining_amount) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Now, user A and B try to take the last stock at the same time.

```
A/B: UPDATE products
     SET remaining_amount = remaining_amount - 1
     WHERE id = 1 and remaining_amount > 0;
```

The questions are:

- Could `remaining_amount` never be negative values? Do we need any explicit pessimistic row locking?
- Which transaction level should I use: `READ COMMITTED`, `REPEATABLE READ`, `SERIALIZABLE` or `READ UNCOMMITTED`(only for MySQL)?
- Does it yield different conclusion with different RDBMS?

#### Related Information

- [(mysql innodb) Is single update statement with "where" transaction safe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/mysql-innodb-is-single-update-statement-with-where-transaction-safe/175247#175247)

  - This question concludes that explicit pessimistic row locking is required for MySQL.
- My Twitter friend RDBMS geek says that:

  - Oracle tries to achieve write consistency; if the target row has been changed, the consecutive UPDATE query is automatically rolled back and it retries with implicit pessimistic row locking. He says that it is described in this book: [Amazon | Expert Oracle Database Architecture | Kyte, Thomas, Kuhn, Darl | Software Development](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/1430262982/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_gl_i_1Y35BV7X7HMDSXB38YV1_0)
  - PostgreSQL has immutable rows and then the old rows are treated as *dead tuple*; so the latter updates will never be applied.

Comment: related? : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem

Comment: Though  it has been downvoted, i'll accept any partial useful information!

Comment: Sorry, I've adeed the unique condition! @MitchWheat

Comment: Possibly it has no problems about deadlocks

Comment: Oracle will indeed lock the row until the first session has committed or rolled back. Once the lock is released the second session will reattempt its update based on the  new values and find nothing to update.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks very much! Postgres' behavior looks to be almost same. What about MySQL 8?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We noticed that each RDBMS(MySQL/Postgres/Oracle) **ALWAYS, AUTOMATICALLY** locks updating rows **WITH ANY TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVELS.** It means that MySQL(InnoDB)'s `READ UNCOMMITTED` works well.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATIONLEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` `BEGIN;` | `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATIONLEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` `BEGIN;` |
| `UPDATE products SET remaining_amount = remaining_amount - 1 WHERE remaining_amount > 0;` |  |
| Query OK, 1 row affected Rows **matched: 1 Changed: 1** Warnings: 0 |  |
|  | `UPDATE products SET remaining_amount = remaining_amount - 1 WHERE remaining_amount > 0;` |
|  | **BLOCKED!!!** |
| `COMMIT;` |  |
|  | Query OK, 0 rows affected Rows **matched: 0 Changed: 0** Warnings: 0 |
|  | `COMMIT;` |

Special Thanks: **[@zyake](https://twitter.com/zyake)**

Other evidences on Postgres: https://twitter.com/zyake/status/1543229753968041984

> When checking if a specific tuple satisfies the update condition or when performing an update operation, **an exclusive lock per page is acquired**, so it is **serialized**.
> https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/e3fcca0d0d2414f3a50d6fd40eddf48b7df81475/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c#L3215
> https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/e3fcca0d0d2414f3a50d6fd40eddf48b7df81475/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c#L3447

## UPDATE: Detailed investigation on MySQL/Postgres

[mpyw-yattemita/mysql-postgres-update-locking-and-isolation-levels](https://github.com/mpyw-yattemita/mysql-postgres-update-locking-and-isolation-levels)

However, it is not guaranteed to be conflict-free whenever a `SELECT` subquery is included. Our investigation revealed that the results vary depending on the transaction isolation level, as follows:

- `UPDATE t SET v=v-1 WHERE id=1 AND v>0`
- `UPDATE t SET v=v-1 WHERE EXISTS(SUBQUERY)`
- `UPDATE t SET v=(SUBQUERY)-1 WHERE id=1 AND v>0`

### Postgres

- **For simple updates or subquery `SET`, use `READ COMMITED`.**
- **For complex subquery `WHERE`, use `REPEATABLE READ` and retry on serialization errors.**

|  | Simple | Subquery WHERE | Subquery SET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| READ COMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 5/6 Broken | ✅ |
| REPEATABLE READ | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error |
| SERIALIZABLE | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error |

#### Subquery WHERE with `READ COMMITED` will be broken:

| [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act before A's commit | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
| Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |

### MySQL

- **For simple updates or subquery `SET`, any transaction isolation level works well.** `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `READ COMMITTED` are recommended.
- **For complex subquery `WHERE`, use `REPEATABLE READ` and retry on deadlock errors.**

|  | Simple | Subquery WHERE | Subquery SET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| READ UNCOMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 4/6 Broken | ✅ |
| READ COMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 5/6 Broken | ✅ |
| REPEATABLE READ | ✅ | ❗ 1/6 Deadlock | ✅ |
| SERIALIZABLE | ✅ | ❗ 1/6 Deadlock | ✅ |

#### Subquery WHERE with `READ UNCOMMITED` will be broken:

| [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act before A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
| Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |

#### Subquery WHERE with `READ COMMITED` will be broken:

| [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act before A's commit | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
| Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |

#### Subquery WHERE with `REPEATABLE READ` will get deadlocks:

| [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act before A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Act after A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ❗ Deadlock |

#### Subquery WHERE with `SERIALIZABLE` will get deadlocks:

| [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act before A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ❗ Deadlock |
| Act after A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a must I would avoid locks and changing isolation levels. Use *Optimistic Locking* instead. There are three implementations of it, but for simplicity I would use the traditional one: adding a `version` column to the table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  remaining_amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  version int default 0 -- new column
);

INSERT INTO products(id, remaining_amount) VALUES (1, 1);

select * from products where id = 1; -- A and B get version 0

UPDATE products
SET remaining_amount = remaining_amount - 1,
    version = version + 1
WHERE id = 1 and remaining_amount > 0
  and version = 0; -- here, version number from previous SELECT
```

The above `UPDATE` returns the count of *updated rows*; we save it in a variable "c".

In this case, either A or B will get to update the row first and "will win" the update. The other one won't update anything.

We can find out which one won by looking at the count "c". If it's 1 then it was able to update, and if it's 0 then it couldn't update. Easy, isn't it?

The downsides are:

- It requires an extra column in the table (maybe not, depending on the strategy),
- Needs an extra `SELECT`, if you weren't doing so already.
- It changes the `UPDATE` query.
- It requires an extra line of code in your app to check the value of `c`.

But, it's blazing fast, safe, and does not require any locking or isolation management.